# Weird floating point error?

Tags: java, processing

I've been trying to generate a pattern of circles using a for loop. However, when it runs everything looks fine except for the 9th ring of circles which is ever so slightly. Having looked at a print out of numbers for that circle everything looks fine, so I can't work out what is going wrong. However, when I add one to the angle value of that ring. i.e. j (the commented out code) it pretty much corrects.

Any idea why this might happen. having looked at all the numbers I can only think it is some math error that I haven't factored in or am I missing something obvious.

Thanks!

[image: ocd trigger warning]

```
          ellipse(325,325,15,15);      
          float div = 1;
          for (int i = i; i < 25; i++)
          {
            div = i*6
            float segment = 360/div;
            float radius = (i*20);
            for (int j = 0; j < 360; j+=segment)
            {
              //if (i==8)
              //{
                //println("before " + j);
                //j+=1;
                //println("after " + j);
              //}
              float x = 325 + (radius*cos(radians(j)));
              float y = 325 + (radius*sin(radians(j)));
              ellipse(x, y, 15, 15);
            }
          }
```

Comment: Change all floats to doubles, change all int divisions to double division. Create an [sscce](http://sscce.org) and let us *experience* your problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, three things, in order of importance. Two of these have already been mentioned.

1) Clean out the `int`s. Variable `i` can be an `int`, but none of the others (especially `j` since it is an angle, not a counter or index), and you want to make sure that all math operations treat numbers as `double`s. Go so far as to designate your constants as `double`s (e.g. use `1d` instead of `1`).

2) Avoid cumulative errors. In your inner `for` loop, you repeatedly add to `j`. Bad. Instead, compute your angle directly based on which circle you're computing.

3) Use `double`, not `float`. You'll get better precision.

I'd do it like this...

```
ellipse(325,325,15,15);      
for (int i = i; i < 25; i++)
{
  double div = i*6d;
  double radius = (i*20d);
  for (int j = 0; j < div; j++)
  {
    double theta = j * 360d / div;
    double x = 325d + (radius*cos(radians(theta)));
    double y = 325d + (radius*sin(radians(theta)));
    ellipse(x, y, 15, 15);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You get the `segment` as a `float`, but then you use an `int` to calculate the degrees.

```
for (int j=0; j < 360; j+=segment)
```

and

```
float x = 325 + (radius*cos(radians(j)));
```

This is what is causing the rounding errors.

And if you make `i` to get a value bigger than `60` the program will never end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `double` instead of float to minimise representation error.

Change the for loop to reduce error.

```
for (int k = 0; k < div; k++) {
    int j = k * 360 / div;
```

This will give you different values for `j` which are likely to be more correct.